# Could this be done in C# function syntax

Tags: c#, function, syntax

I'm developing a very specific graphical filter function.
The whole math behind it is under development, it's pretty long and it changes often. I wish I had some nicer control over the function testing.

In C# a function has an input pattern like:

`Private int MyFunction (argument1,argument2,argument3....)`

However I would like to call the function like:

```
Result = MyFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3).MathTest2
```

And where I could define any new MathTestX inside the function itself.
So my call to the function wouldn't need to be adjusted in all programs that make use of it. Is something like this possible? Or must I declare an enum or constants, to do it like below:

```
Result = MyFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3,MathTest2)  // and thus update all progs that make use of it.
```

If it is possible then its also critical to me that it wont require stress on a system memory wise or cpu wise. Because the filter needs to work on a high-speed cam 60 frames a sec, so my math needs to stay fast. I got only a millisecond to work with.

I realize that the whole thing becomes close to object notation (like calling .net function) like `L= MyString.length`. Creating a function inside an object might do the trick but I have doubts here about speed if should do that, speed is a critical factor here.

Comment: `MyFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3).MathTest2` would imply that `MathTest2` is something related to the *return value* of the function, If you have to pass something to the function then pass it through the parameters. `Enum`, class object, whatever you like.

Comment: One more thing to add, Don't worry about the performance *yet*. First make it workable and if you see any performance issues, then use Memory profiler/.Net profilers to find the cause and rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for you is this;

Create a static class:

```
public static class XM{

     public static MathTest MyFunction(this MathTest mt, arg1,arg2,arg3){
          //do calcs here on MathTest setting values based on arg1,2,and 3
          return mt;
     }
}
```

This allows you to call it like this....

```
  var result = MathTest2.MyFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

This assumes that MathTest2 inherits the base class MathTest.  You can create extension methods for MathTest2 as well.  In addition you can create static extension mehtods that take in functions (typeof MyFunction) but the way shown above makes a bit more sense.

This is how you build a "Fluent" interface for MathTests.  Eventually you would be able to do things like this:

```
  MathTest2.ValidateCircleAnswers().ValidateOtherQuestions().ComputeTotalRight()
```

Comment: Well yeah eventually that's where i would like to go to too 


:))

Comment: But ehm how do relate MathTest and MathTest2 to eachother ?

Comment: MathTest is an abstraction of all things in common with say "MayTest2", "MathTest3" etc.  But if you are not at that point yet, just make the extension method for MathTest2.

Comment: Thanks John i will investigate Extension methods, my problem is I kinda rolled into programming with no educated background in it, 
In my job its more the combination a part of coding / designing / engineering and  a lot of math and mostly creativity.. I learned a lot of coding languages (~12) but i lack programming terminology  such words terms as  "Fluent" and "extension methods". A problem in my self education. I learn new things only when i stumble on them, like these..

Comment: Yes, all of us are in same boat because in the technical world every day brings new things we have to learn... It's very difficult to stay focused now a days...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are to focused on too many problems at once. So break down your problems:

1.
Convenience of using certain notation - I personally wouldn't place too much on this. What you are asking for is [easily doable with generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) like:

```
private T MyFunction<T>(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    // ... method body
}
```

where type you pass in as T would have some property you wish to get. Then you would call function like:

```
MyFunction<MyClass>(arg1, arg2, arg3).MyClassProperty
```

2. As for speed - premature optimization is evil. So make a prototype and run it... only then you'll see if you need to optimize anything / give up some of the convenience you are chasing in #1. From my experience in majority of cases C# positively surprises people when it comes to speed.

Comment: the problem with speed is that my math has to work on camera input, and i cannot realy lower the frame rate of it, or else other parts of the machine wont work... but so far even if its c# and not c++ i'm doing pretty good on speed with the math i use.